# Why is non atomic assertation matching by two, by one in reverse?

Tags: c, regex, pcre

So I've slightly modified [the example on the pcre2 page](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html#SEC21):

```
^(?*.*(?<abstrptr>[*]((?<qualifiers>\bconst\b|\brestrict\b|\bvolatile\b))*+(?C11)))(.*?\b(?&abstrptr)\b)+
```

I've a function in C that on callout 11 prints the group inside the named group abstrptr (so the qualifier).

Here is what I'm matching against:

```
*const*restrict*volatile*const
```

And my output is (the first number is the group id inside abstrptr):

```
 2 - const
 2 - restrict
 2 - volatile
 2 - const
full match is: 0 - 30, *const*restrict*volatile*const
```

I can't understand why is the output in this order - I simply want to make it print in reverse (i.e. const volatile restrict const).

EDIT: OK something like this:

```
^(?*.*(?<abstrptr>[*]((?<qualifiers>\bconst\b|\brestrict\b|\bvolatile\b))*+(?C11)))(\b(?&abstrptr)\b.*?)+
```

does it but it doesn't match the pattern any more (full match).

Comment: try this one: ``^.*(?<abstrptr>\*(?<qualifiers>const|restrict|volatile)\b)(?C11)(*F)|^.*?(?&abstrptr)+``

Comment: @Michail It does the callouts in reverse but it also doesn't match the whole pattern.

Comment: It match a whole pattern. Let's see this in tester (I remove callout as Regex01.com can't understand it):

https://regex101.com/r/DslQHH/1

Comment: @Michail Yup it does - I don't know what I was looking - thanks so much - if you make this an answer I'll upvote and accept. But also I would love an explanation of how it works too.

Comment: I was doing some crazy recursion which depended on certain group to be set to print in the right order (which was a huge drawback for more complex cases - i.e. recursion inside another recursion).